# How to add labels to plotly Box chart like Scatter chart?

Tags: python, plotly

I couldn't find the way to add text labels to plotly/dash box plot like you could add it to a scatterplot. In the example below, for ScatterPlot x=qty, y=price and you can then add Salesperson to the graph when the cursor is on Marker. For adding this I use the 'text' argument.

In the second example for BoxPlot when x=date, y=price I want to add salesperson in the same way. It would be very useful in case of outliers to see immediately who was the salesperson for that purchase. I looked in the documentation, but there is no clue. I assume it's not possible but still decided to try my luck here.

#### scatterplot:

```
import plotly.offline as pyo
import plotly.graph_objs as go


purchase={'date':['11/03/2021','12/03/2021','14/03/2021','11/03/2021'],
          'price':[300, 400,200, 200],
          'currency':['eur', 'usd','usd','usd'],
          'qty':[200, 300, 400, 500],
          'salesman':['AC', 'BC', "CC", 'DC']}
pur=pd.DataFrame(purchase)
pur



data = [go.Scatter(
    x = pur['qty'],
    y = pur['price'],
    mode = 'markers',
    text=pur['salesman'],
    marker = dict(
        size = 12,
        color = 'rgb(51,204,153)',
        symbol = 'pentagon',
        line = dict(
            width = 2,
        )
    )
)]
layout = go.Layout(
    title = 'Random Data Scatterplot', 
    xaxis = dict(title = 'Some random x-values'), 
    yaxis = dict(title = 'Some random y-values'), 
    hovermode ='closest' 
)
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)

fig.show()
```

#### boxplot:

```
import plotly.offline as pyo
import plotly.graph_objs as go

x = pur['date']
y = pur['price']

data = [
    go.Box(
        y=y,
        x=x,
        text=pur['salesman']
    )
]
layout = go.Layout(
    title = 'box_plot'
)
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data you currently have is not suitable for boxplot. If you try to plot a boxplot with your data, the list `[300, 400,200, 200]` is used only once for the first date. For the other dates, there is no data.

I will show a simpler example with my own data.

#### dataset.csv

```
salesman,sales
alan,1.8
bary,2.3
copa,4.2
dac,1.19
eila,2.3
foo,2.5
gary,0.1
holland,10
```

#### code

```py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd
import plotly.io as pio
pio.renderers.default = 'browser'

df = pd.read_csv("deletelater")

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Box(
    y=df["sales"],
    name='12/12/22',
    customdata=df["salesman"],
    hovertemplate='<b>sales: %{y}</b><br>salesperson: %{customdata}'
))


fig.show()
```

#### Diagram

[image]

As you can see, the name of the outlier salesperson is displayed on the hover label.